# How to specify the size of the cluster?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

Is there any cluster algorithm (k-means,...) in which I can define the size of the cluster?

I have a large group of people and I want to make cluster with size of 9 people each.

At the moment I use this [same size k-means](https://elki-project.github.io/tutorial/same-size_k_means). However, the code becomes extremly slow for data with more than 100 people.

Maybe there is some parameter that I can set, in order to define the size of the cluster?

Comment: one of the main problems with K-means is inconsistent cluster shapes and sizes. Maybe, you can try DBSCAN

Comment: As far as I know (please correct me!), you can not set the cluster size in DBSCAN

Comment: yes, you are right but with little intuition you can get clusters of same size,

Answer (score 0):

You can easily modify that code to use exactly 9 elements per cluster (at least of the number is divisible by 9). You likely can further optimize it by doing more swaps, only recompute what is necessary, integrate advancements of the many other faster k-means algorithms instead of Lloyd's, etc.

But it very clearly won't scale for a *huge* number of clusters.

It just is **not a clustering problem**. You likely are abusing an algorithm to solve a different problem, and so it doesn't work well... And the actual problem (likely some variant of knapsack, set cover, bin packing) is almost certainly NP-hard, so you do have a pretty tough problem anyway. I'd go with a fast greedy approach and use the best of several attempts, then at most do a little bit of swap optimization to fine tune the result. Look for *optimization* literature, try to phrase it as ILP or QLP, and use an ILP resp. QLP solver etc.